# How do I modify the value of a custom global style using Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

For instance, if I write:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --p-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

It will define a variable, and I can use it in my scopes:

```
<dom-module id="so-example">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host p {
        color: var(--p-color);
      }
    </style>

    <p>this is a test</p>
  </template>
  <script>Polymer({ is: 'so-example' });</script>
</dom-module>
...
<so-example></so-example>
```

Now, let's say I want to change the style only in the scope of the `so-example`. I can write:

```
var el = document.querySelector('so-example');
el.customStyle['--p-color'] = 'red';
el.updateStyles();
```

And this will magically change all the paragraphs' color in the scope.
But the reason I use the `is="custom-style"` block is because `--p-color` is used in various different elements. And now I can't use the above method to change its value. If I do so, it will only change the color of the scope as I said.

Is there a way to modify this variable when it was defined in the document scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update styles globally with `Polymer.updateStyles({/* new styles */})` instead of calling `updateStyles()` on each element.

```
Polymer.updateStyles({
  '--p-color': 'blue'
});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-bar'
  });
});

function changeColor() {
  Polymer.updateStyles({
    '--p-color': 'blue'
  });
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    :root {
      --p-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <x-bar></x-bar>
  <button onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        p {
          color: var(--p-color);
        }
      </style>
      <p>x-foo</p>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
    <dom-module id="x-bar">
    <template>
      <style>
        p {
          color: var(--p-color);
        }
      </style>
      <p>x-bar</p>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

Comment: oh hey.. usually i don't write a comment to just say thanks and will just accept but I have to say thanks for correcting my post typos and for having taken the time to write a demo.

Comment: @ballangddang No problem :)